# Insert N elements from one container to other using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I want to insert elements that exist in container `A` to container `B` in a way that is equivalent to the following:

```
auto iter = /* iterator from somewhere in A */
for (auto i=0; i<N && iter++ != A.cend(); i++)
    B.push_back(*iter);
```

But using insert instead and no for loop, something like this;

```
B.insert(B.end(), iter, iter + N);
```

Comment: Did you try it? It should work. Which container you're using?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" well, that depends on the container, and you did't provide that information. http://ideone.com/4QQY0r

Comment: @kfsone that code is different than what I had. I want to safely insert N elements, where that inserts everything.

Comment: @AnonymousEntity since you are using iterators, that's irrelevant semantics, http://ideone.com/E4HnrK

Comment: My point is you need to provide more information if you want a useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

auto a_iter = /* iterator from somewhere in A */, a_end = A.end();
std::copy_n(a_iter, std::min(N, std::distance(a_iter, a_end)), std::inserter(B, B.end()));
```

As a standalone algorithm:

```
template<typename IterT, typename CollT>
std::insert_iterator<CollT> insert_n(
    IterT a_iter, IterT a_end,
    typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::difference_type N,
    CollT& B
) {
    return std::copy_n(
        a_iter,
        std::min(N, std::distance(a_iter, a_end)),
        std::inserter(B, B.end())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use `std::copy_if` with an appropriate lambda function.

By example, if your containers are vectors of int, in this way

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int>  a { 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19 };

   auto i1 = a.cbegin()+3;
   auto i2 = a.cbegin()+7;

   std::vector<int> c1;
   std::vector<int> c2;

   constexpr int N = 5;

   std::copy_if(i1, a.cend(), std::back_inserter(c1),
                [&](int){ static int pos = -1; return ++pos < N; });

   std::copy_if(i2, a.cend(), std::back_inserter(c2),
                [&](int){ static int pos = -1; return ++pos < N; });

   std::cout << "c1.size() = " << c1.size() << std::endl;  // cout 5
   std::cout << "c2.size() = " << c2.size() << std::endl;  // cout 2

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `vector` container and perhaps for many more containers that's work just like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        vector<int> A = {4,5,6};
        vector<int> B = {1,2,3};

        unsigned int n = 5;

        B.insert(B.end(), A.begin(), A.begin() + (n > B.size() ? B.size(): n));

        for (auto it = B.begin(); it != B.end(); it++)
                cout << *it << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can see the doc [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), It's in the `c++11` tab, `range (3)` signature.